# Selecting different rows in a dataset in Jupyter notebook using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to select first row and the last 5 rows in the dataframe.
So, Here's the code that works fine for me:

```
df_two_wheeler_bottom5 = df_two_wheeler.iloc[[0,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1],:]
```

So i want to use range to write less number. So i update my code as follows:

```
df_two_wheeler_bottom5 = df_two_wheeler.iloc[[0,-5:-1],:]
```

After that the code encountered with Syntax Error. The error is decribed bellow:

> File "", line 1
>       df_two_wheeler_bottom5 = df_two_wheeler.iloc[[0,-5:-1],:]
>                                                         ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any help about that would be greatful.

Comment: Though its better to learn to do things in different ways. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html), but is necessary change select with `-1` to `0`:

```
df_two_wheeler = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdefghijkl')})
print (df_two_wheeler)
    A
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
5   f
6   g
7   h
8   i
9   j
10  k
11  l

df_two_wheeler_bottom5 = df_two_wheeler.iloc[np.r_[0,-5:0]]
print(df_two_wheeler_bottom5)
    A
0   a
7   h
8   i
9   j
10  k
11  l
```

**Detail**:

```
print (np.r_[0,-5:0])
[ 0 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1]
```

Comment: this is a proper usecase for using `np.r_`

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

```
df_two_wheeler_bottom5 = df_two_wheeler.iloc[[0, *range(-5, 0)],:]
```

The `[0, *range(-5, 0)]` just expands to `[0,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1]`.